# Python select ith element in OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddictionary

I have a snippet of code which orders a dictionary alphabetically.
Is there a way to select the ith key in the ordered dictionary and return its corresponding value? i.e.

```
import collections
initial = dict(a=1, b=2, c=2, d=1, e=3)
ordered_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(initial.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
print(ordered_dict)

OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('e', 3)])
```

I want to have some function along the vein of...

```
select = int(input("Input dictionary index"))
#User inputs 2
#Program looks up the 2nd entry in ordered_dict (c in this case)
#And then returns the value of c (2 in this case)
```

How can this be achieved?
Thanks.

(Similar to [Accessing Items In a ordereddict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058140/accessing-items-in-a-ordereddict), but I only want to output the value of the key-value pair.)

Comment: try `ordered_dict[ordered_dict.keys()[index]]`

Comment: @IonutHulub, I tried (without the user input bit) print(ordered_dict[ordered_dict.keys()[2]]) and received the error, TypeError: "KeysView" object does not support indexing.

Comment: ``lambda`` is written with ``b`` before the ``d``.

Comment: @DanielLee My apologies, corrected.

Comment: you could avoid sorting the whole `initial` dictionary if input is a small index by using `heapq`: `result = initial[heapq.nsmallest(select+1, initial)[-1]]`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Python 2:

If you want to access the key:

```
>>> ordered_dict = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('e', 3)])
>>> ordered_dict.keys()[2]
'c'
```

If want to access the value:

```
>>> ordered_dict.values()[2]
2
```

If you're using Python 3, you can convert the `KeysView` object returned by the `keys` method by wrapping it as a list:

```
>>> list(ordered_dict.keys())[2]
'c'
>>> list(ordered_dict.values())[2]
2
```

Not the prettiest solution, but it works.

Answer (score 12):

Using [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is efficient here, because we don't have to create any intermediate lists, for the sake of subscripting.

```
from itertools import islice
print(next(islice(ordered_dict.items(), 2, None)))
```

If you want just the value, you can do

```
print ordered_dict[next(islice(ordered_dict, 2, None))]
```

Comment: Ahh, not quite what I want. Your method returns the key-value pair, but I only want the code to return the _value of the key_

Comment: +1. `islice` is preferable but for a small dictionary `list(ordered_dict.values())[2]` might be faster i.e., don't assume what is faster until you've measured it

Comment: @JFSebastian, Interesting, what makes islice preferable for small dictionaries? Just the logic behind the code or something else?

Comment: @Pingk He says, `islice` is preferable but not for small dicts

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong, but what makes it faster/slower compared to list? @thefourtheye

Comment: is it really faster to use the key to index instead of using islice over `.values`?

Answer (score 6):

Do you have to use an OrderedDict or do you just want a dict-like type that supports indexing? If the latter, then consider a sorted dict object. Some implementations of SortedDict (which orders pairs based on the key sort order) support fast n-th indexing. For example, the [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) project has a [SortedDict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html) type with random-access indexing.

In your case it would look something like:

```
>>> from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
>>> sorted_dict = SortedDict(a=1, b=2, c=2, d=1, e=3)
>>> print sorted_dict.iloc[2]
'c'
```

If you do a lot of lookups, this will be **a lot** faster than repeatedly iterating to the desired index.

Comment: Thanks very much, and I may use this in the future, but the method I've logged as the correct answer does a very similar method to this.
I'm curious though, will the dictionary stay ordered if I change the value of one of the k-v pairs, or will it re-arrange itself like the standard dictionary?

Comment: Yes, it will automatically stay sorted by the keys. It'll be much faster than the accepted solution if your making edits to the dictionary and then indexing.

Comment: Awesome, I'll probably use this next time then. I don't think I'll change the accepted answer, but I'll vote you up.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along these lines (od is the ordered dict):

```
def get_idx(od, idx):
   from itertools import islice
   idx = (idx + len(od)) % len(od)
   t = islice(od.items(), idx, idx + 1)
   return next(t)

>>>x

OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('k', 23), ('t', 41), ('q', 23)])

>>>get_idx(x, 1)
('b', 3)
>>>get_idx(x, 2)
('k', 23)
>>>get_idx(x, 4)
('q', 23)
>>>get_idx(x, -1)
('q', 23)
>>>get_idx(x, -2)
('t', 41)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't underestimate just a plain 'ole [for](http://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loop:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od=OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('e', 3)])

def ith(od, tgt):
    for i, t in enumerate(od.items()):
        if i==tgt:
            print('element {}\'s key is "{}"'.format(i,t[0]))
            break
    else:
        print('element {} not found'.format(tgt)) 

ith(od, 2)
# element 2's key is "c"
ith(od, 20) 
# element 20 not found
```

The advantage here is that the loop will break as soon as the desired element is found and returns a sensible result if not found...

The disadvantage is that relative slices are not supported.